# How to make Ajax request to controller function in yii

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2

This is my js code:

```
var durl = "<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/Site/ReqAJAX";

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: durl,
    data: {_csrf:'<?=\Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>'},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(msg) { 
        alert("Success "+msg); 
    },
    error: function(err) {   
        alert(JSON.stringify(err)); 
    } 
});
```

This is the error i get:

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? Can you describe the error you get? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: error:object not found   the issue is with the url may be

Comment: What file does this code live in?

Comment: If you are using clean urls, the controller's first letter is lower case, and after a uppercase there's a dash. So maybe you have to call to site/req-ajax? Anyway, post an screenshot or something so we can try to help, not to try to suppose ;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually create the JS inside the PHP instead of the other way around and assigning all required variables that I will need inside the JS block for readability. It usually helps me to find the bugs more easily. Also, I do use the Yii2 UrlManager to create the urls, not JS, because that will ensure the url is correct. (given it is setup correctly of course ;))

Perhaps this will help finding the issues.

```
<?php
$url = Url::to(['/site/req-ajax']);
$data = json_encode([Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken]);
$js =<<<JS
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "$url",
    data: $data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(msg) { 
        alert("Success "+msg); 
    },
    error: function(err) {   
        alert(JSON.stringify(err)); 
    } 
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Comment: i have added the code in my view page i.e index.php but getting the sane error i have also put the image of error that i got..

Comment: it shows in that result <title>Object not found</title>

do you need to pass additional data to the url for the ajax call to be processed correctly?

Comment: no there is no additional parameter to be pass to a function in controller..i just want a simple ajax request to a function in controller from my view page